# How to save multiple button selections?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 buttons representing cities, I have assigned them `tags` via `Attribute Inspector` as follows, `CityA as 0, CityB as 1, CityC as 2`.

I have an empty array for tags

```
var cityTag: [Int] = []
```

Then in IBAction method

```
@IBAction func cityButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    cityTag = [sender.tag!]
}
```

I have an attribute `citySelected` in core data of type `Transformable`

When I am saving the data, it is remembering only the last city selected and output on console is

```
Record Saved Successfully
citySelected = "(\n    2\n)";
```

But it should be like this below, because I selected all cities

```
Record Saved Successfully
citySelected = "(\n    0\n    1\n    2\n)";
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you removed my accepted answer by mistake.. Cheers! :)

Comment: I am sorry, I did this because your answer is doing job but when I am selecting and deselecting cities, it is still remembering the cities I deselected. So I thought of keeping the question open

Comment: Have updated my answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its like you are reinitializing the array everytime. Rather append or remove new element like this:

```
if(cityTag.contains(sender.tag!)) {
     if let index = cityTag.index(of: sender.tag!) {
         cityTag.remove(at: index)
     }
} else {
     cityTag.append(sender.tag!)
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

you should not use
cityTag = [sender.tag!]
you must use
cityTag.append(sender.tag!)

Answer (score 1):

You should append to the array

```
cityTag += [sender.tag!]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `cityButtonPressed` method, you are assigning the tag value of the button to the `array`. This is overriding the last array assignment. It means first time you are saying that `cityTag = 1`, but as soon as you are pressing second button your `cityTag = 2` . To avoid this you will have to collect all the tags by appending them in the `cityTag` array.

To append them use this line of code:

```
cityTag.append(sender.tag!)
```

I hope this gives you clear idea about your problem.

Comment: That was pretty clear, but it should be like cityTag.append(sender.tag!) .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try use Set instead of Array , like :

```
var cityTag: Set = []

@IBAction func cityButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    if cityTag.contains(sender.tag) == false {
       cityTag.insert(sender.tag)
     }else{
     cityTag.remove(sender.tag)
     }

  }
```

Comment: What does this accomplish?

Comment: You save your tag uniquely and remove once you click the button once again, what saves the state of all selected cities . What you did is assigning a new array with one element every click you make, that's why you have only the last one

Comment: That is perfect solution but I am getting an error saying "Cannot convert value of type [Any] to Set" as well as my Xcode is breaking down.

Answer (score 0):

**I guess you also need to check this:**

```
if cityTag.contains(sender.tag!) {
    //You can remove the unselected city tag from cityTag array
    print(“already exists“)
}
else{
    //Here you add selected city tag to cityTag array
    cityTag.append(sender.tag!)
}
```